# After traveling to Austria, now Google and G+ seem to be stuck in German rather than English

Tags: language, default-settings

I've read many supposed fixes, but none of them worked for me. Does anyone know how to change my defaults to English?  Note: When I try to set English as the default, it already seems to be. And yet I have to keep right-clicking to translate-to-English. Is there no way to fix this??

Comment: `I've read many supposed fixes, but none of them worked for me.` Which fixes did you try? Cookies, website-settings,..?

Comment: Also, can you describe exactly what you did to get into this situation? Did you merely *use* your computer normally in Austria, or did you make any configuration changes? And, at the risk of asking a dumb question: are you going to `google.com` or something else (like `google.co.at`), and is the former automatically redirecting you to the latter?

Comment: For the moment it seems to be working as it should, but seemingly not via what I've tried (including deleting all cookies, etc), unless it was a delayed response.  But it's all irrelevant now that it suddenly started assuming I want to see English.  All's well.